# Cannot create Document Library

Tags: 2010, document-library, library

For some reason I cannot create a Document Library, as the option for this is gone (for example via Site Actions -> View All Site Content -> Create).

[image: The document library option is gone]

The option in the red circle is gone. And if I choose Site Actions -> New Document Library, I just get a blank dialog:

[image: New document library modal from site actions is blank]

Edit: It does not work from Site Actions -> Manage Content and Structure either.

How can I get the possibility to create document libraries back?

How can it not be there? Is there a feature in the parent site collection that should be activated? (the site in question is located at xxx/sites/SiteName)

Comment: Possibly a silverlight issue. Disable silverlight and enable it once again. Also can you try doing the same from "Manage site content and structure" through site settings and see whether it works or not.

Comment: Just tested, it does not work from "Manage Content and Structure" either

Comment: Are you able to create through powershell or visual studio code ?

Comment: Is your content database or site collection set to Read-Only or possibly out of space?

Comment: Is this by chance a sub-site of another site you are not owner of? I have seen this on my site when giving others ownership to a sub-site with lists and libraries.

Comment: Well, it is a sub-site of the root site collection, which I am not the owner of. How have you solved this when you have experienced this?

Comment: @DaveWise: Im not 100% sure, but I don't think so. And even if the site collection was read-only, the "template" shouldn't disappear? And there are other templates, just not the Document Library :/ I dont think Im out of space either, I only have < 1000 documents.

Comment: @Paulster2: Did you find a solution when you experienced this?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not. I resorted to creating the Lists/Libraries for them. It seems to me the Lists/Libraries are owned by the main site. You'd have to have permissions to creat them there in order to create them on the sub-site. There may be a simple fix for this, but I haven't had time to get it deciphered yet. Maybe someone on here has the answer for us?